# directing messages ('intros') at a certain user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple rails app: I have 2 models, user and intro [which is simply a message]. Each message has a sender (user) and receiver (user). Here's the intro model (validations omitted):

```
class Intro < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"

  default_scope order: 'intros.created_at DESC'
end
```

and now the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    has_many :sent_intros, foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Intro"
    has_many :received_intros, foreign_key: "receiver_id", dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Intro"

    before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
    before_save :create_remember_token

    private

        def create_remember_token
            self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end
end
```

The app currently lets the current user submit an intro into a form and associate with that message (a home page shows sent_intros). However, I could use some help in the intros_controller/create method when it comes to the received_intros function. How do I let an intro that is created by the current user be associated with (i.e. sent to) another specific user so that I can route it to a recipient's inbox? Thank you.

```
class IntrosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create
    @sent_intro = current_user.sent_intros.build(params[:intro])
    if @sent_intro.save
        flash[:success] = "Intro sent!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def index
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're allowing the current_user to assign a `receiver` to an intro they create? You need to have an input on your form that allows a user to set a valid `receiver_id`, and you need to add receiver_id to attr_accessible:

```
class Intro < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :receiver_id 

  #Rest of your code
end
```

With that, when your `intro` is created, it will be properly associated with both a sender and a receiver. You would then be able to access a current_user's received intros with the method `current_user.received_intros`

You may want to add some validation to the `Intro` model to make sure both a receiver and a sender exist.

EDIT: You can add the receiver_id field to your code in the comments like so:

```
<!-- In your first view -->
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %> 
<h1>All users</h1> 
<%= will_paginate %> 
<ul class="users"> 
  <%= @users.each do |user| %> 
    <%= render user %> 
    <%= render 'shared/intro_form', :user => user %>  <!-- make sure you pass the user to user intro_form -->
  <% end %> 
</ul> 
<%= will_paginate %> 

<!-- shared/intro_form -->
<%= form_for(@sent_intro) do |f| %> 
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %> 
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Shoot them an intro..." %> 
  </div> 
  <%= observe_field :intro_content, :frequency => 1, :function => "$('intro_content').value.length" %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => user.id %> <!-- Add this to pass the right receiver_id to the controller -->
  <%= f.submit "Send intro", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: will need to add those validations! would i assign the receiver here?<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
 <%= @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
  <%= render 'shared/intro_form' %>
 <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>

Comment: Uh, where is your form/link to the create action? You have `render 'shared/intro_form'` there - I suspect it would live in there?

Comment: oh, sorry, how's this? <%= form_for(@sent_intro) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Shoot them an intro..." %>
 </div>
  <%= observe_field :intro_content, :frequency => 1,
      :function => "$('intro_content').value.length" %>
 <%= f.submit "Send intro", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>